# How to convert from hexdecimal string to hexadecimal integer in MIPS (using MARS)?

Tags: assembly, hex, mips

I've been stuck on part of my lab in MIPS using Mars, where 3 program arguments are entered and stored in registers (not the same as prompts and user inputs; there is no prompting) in hexadecimal ASCII strings. The arguments are in the form 0x12345678, 0xABCDEF01, etc. They need to be output in sorted ascending order in single precision floating point and then in decimal. My approach to the lab is to offset the "0x" and loop through the rest of the string. For each number 48 is subtracted and for each capital letter, 55 is subtracted. Then continue to the next string and then the next and store them in registers. Then my plan is to sort them and then somehow convert to single precision floating point and then somehow to decimal.

I'm not sure how the hexadecimal integer is stored.

I'm fairly new to this language and have a weak/nonexistent background in it. This is what I have so far that I am stuck on:

```
# convert ASCII strings to hexadecimal integer
lh $a0, 2($a1)  # offset the "0x" portion
lb $t1, 0($a1)
addi $t0, $zero, 0  # i = 0
addi $t1, $zero, 8  # x = 8, to iterate thru the 8 bits

While: 
bge  $t0, $t1, Done     # while (i < y) 
    # if number subtract 48
    # if letter subtract 55
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # i = i + 1, update to next byte
    j While
Done:
```

```
#   tempreg1 = 1st byte
#        #need to offset by 2 for "0x" *2($a0)
#        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) *loop through the 1st string:      
#             if (0 < tempreg1 < 9)
#             { 
#       arg1value += tempreg1 - ASCII value of '0'
#             }
#             if (A < tempreg1 < F)
#             { 
#       arg1value += tempreg1 - ASCII value of 'A' + 10
#             }
```

I'm extremely lost so anything helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make it work in C first; don't just assume your pseudo code works.  When you have working C code, then translate that faithfully into assembly.

Comment: I never learned C, we were just asked to do this lab with little background. My professor is subpar.